# Change URL of a saved HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML so this question might sound a bit lame. Anyways I have a saved webpage on my desktop that when i open it in google chrome i want it to show a specific URL instead of its current location. Any ideas how i might get this to work?
I tried using the history.pushState but i have no idea why it is not working. I created a simple page for now to test it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setURL()
{
    history.pushState("Test","page2", "www.test.com");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="setURL()">Set Url</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this.  the reason behind it that is.  So far, from what you've given I wouldn't spend much time on it.

Comment: Since whenever i open the saved html page, in the URL i get the file location. I want it to show a specific URL to make it seem as if the page is actually being used on-line and not accessed from the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how it works. It's used to change the page location, without reloading the content, on the same domain. For example: you're on the index. Then you click the "about" page, it will change the url from `www.hello.com` to `www.hello.com/about`.

With additional JS in use, you could make it load the changes to make it look like the about page without loading the entire thing (but this is unrelated to what you want; just explaining an application for it.)

It does not allow for complete URL overwriting and your desktop file is not considered to be the same domain as your website (security limitation).

If this is to fool someone: you won't be able to do it.

Comment: Actually i want to load the file i have saved on my desktop and make it show the URL of its actual Location online. It seems to be possible using `history.pushState` but somehow it is not working for me

Comment: Rewrote my answer to better reflect your question. If you're trying to do it because your page uses `window.location` and working offline breaks things there, then we can discuss other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

<p:history.pushState;>

not sure if it works, but you can try it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35429698)